# Is there a standard way to create "combined" Windows cursors (e.g. Arrow+Stop)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

It is well known that the WinAPI offers a number of [default cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Among these, there is for example the default arrow (`IDC_ARROW`) and a "stop" icon (`IDC_NO`).

When using drag'n'drop in the Windows Explorer (e.g. in Windows 7), you can notice that Windows shows a combination of the two aforementioned cursors when dragging a file to some place where it cannot be dropped. This cursor does not exist as a .cur file and it cannot be configured in Windows' mouse setup.

I didn't stumble upon any obvious function to "combine" cursors, so I'm wondering if there's a default way in the WinAPI to create a cursor like the one in the example, or if I have to toy around with the two cursors manually and blit them together into a new cursor on my own.

Comment: The cursors you describe are set by the system in response to the [`DROPEFFECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693457.aspx) returned from [`IDropTarget::DragOver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680129.aspx). The Windows API does not provide a way to combine cursors. You need to construct the bitmap yourself and call [`CreateCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648385.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable: Post this as answer, this is accurate answer, I think. :-)

Comment: These cursors are embedded resources in c:\windows\system32\ole32.dll.  You can look at them with Visual Studio, use File + Open + File.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but these cursors are not necessarily the default cursors that Windows uses - i.e. they look like the old default cursors that were being used up to WinXP, but the Aero cursors look different.